# How to handle word boundary in FreeMarker when replacing string?

Tags: freemarker

When using FreeMarker, I want to replace some words in the template, but `replace` function does not handle word boundary, so my output is messed. Is it possible handle word boundary in FreeMarker? Thanks!

**Edit:**
The word boundary question is solved, but I have another question about `backreference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found I should use the third optional flag 'r' to tell FreeMarker that I am using regular expression. For my purpose, I use something like this:

```
block?replace("\\b${arg}\\b", "__${arg}", "r")
```

Note we must use `\\b` for the word boundary matching.